# JEE, JPA facade edit many to many relation

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee

I'm facing an issue i can't figure out.

I got 2 entities : User and Course with a Many to Many relationship

User.java

```
public class User implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id

  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private String username;
  private String password;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
  @JoinTable(
    name="USR_COURSES",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="USR_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"),
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="COURSE_ID",referencedColumnName="ID"))
  private List<Course> courses;

  ...
```

Course.java

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames="CODE"))
public class Course implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private String code;
  private String name;
  private String content;

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy="courses",cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
  private List<User> users;

  ...
```

If i create a user and set him some courses, the join table will be updated with the new relations between the User and the Courses.

However if i want to *edit* a user by adding him courses, the join table is not update :

```
  List<Course> test = myUser.getCourse();
  test.add(facade.find(1l));
  myUser.setCourse(test);
  userFacade.edit(myUser);
```

I'm using NetBean and the AbstractFacade generated.

Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the cascade to work in that case you would need to set dependencies in the both sides of the ManyToMany relationship.

That means that you would need to do the following:

```
List<Course> test = myUser.getCourse();
Course course = facade.find(1l); 
course.getUsers().add(myUser); 
test.add(course);
myUser.setCourse(test);
userFacade.edit(myUser);
```

When you query for the Course you do not get the user list because you only have Cascade.MERGE set up on that relationship. This means that you need to set it manually as above.

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer ! It does the job ! Do you have any idea i can do in order do directly get my User list ?